# Note at the end of the table in Latex

Tags: tables

I have some tables in Latex and I need to add some notes at the end, I tried this code, but the note that I have to add is too large for the table and I dont know how to fix it, there is another way to do it?

```
    \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(25)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Median} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(75)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 A & 1.539 & 2.896 & 0.140 & 0.218 & 0.420 & 2.820 & 5.540 \\ 
 B 1.722 & 1.871 & 0.190 & 0.355 & 0.630 & 3.090 & 5.630 \\ 
 C & 1.889 & 1.822 & 0.280 & 0.540 & 0.930 & 3.185 & 5.555 \\  
 D & 3.259 & 1.274 & 1.348 & 2.214 & 2.896 & 4.478 & 5.765 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{8}{l}{Note: xxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Comment: If you just put the text after the `\end{tabular}` it should work.

Comment: You might use `threeparttable`.